# How to correctly dispose potentially ofphaned classes in case of exceptions?

Tags: c#, dispose, raii, using-statement

I've just recently started using the full ruleset of Code Analysis in a few of our projects. One of the warnings that really made me think more carefully about `IDisposable` classes is the [CA2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx). I've got many instances of it complaining that some disposable objects were not being disposed on every exception path.

Thus the question is: what is the more correct way of handling disposal of objects in case of exceptions in the rest of the method, before returning? For instance, this method:

```
public MyDisposable GetMyDisposable()
{
    var disposable = new MyDisposable();
    disposable.MethodThatCanThrowExceptions();
    return disposable;
}
```

Would raise such warning, because if the `MethodThatCanThrowExceptions` method does indeed throw an exception, the caller will not receive the disposable instance, and thus no one will be able to dispose it before the garbage collector kicks in.

The pattern I've been using is something along these lines:

```
public MyDisposable GetMyDisposable()
{
    var disposable = new MyDisposable();
    try
    {
        disposable.MethodThatCanThrowExceptions();
    }
    catch
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
    return disposable;
}
```

But I've seen a few people mention the use of a `finally` block instead of catch, with a Boolean value to signal that there was a problem in the rest of the code, like this:

```
public MyDisposable GetMyDisposable()
{
    bool ok;
    var disposable = new MyDisposable();
    try
    {
        disposable.MethodThatCanThrowExceptions();
        ok = true;
        return disposable;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!ok) disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Between these two, what is the best way to handle this scenario? Is there any other, perhaps simpler, method for handling this situation? I programmed a bit in C++ and in that language it is common to use a class to handle these disposable situations, called a Scope Guard. From what I saw, that pattern supports a `Release` method, so that you can wrap code with disposal behavior, but *cancel* the actual disposal on some condition. In C#, I assume it would look like this:

```
public MyDisposable GetMyDisposable()
{
    using (var disposable = new MyDisposable())
    {
        disposable.MethodThatCanThrowExceptions();
        return release disposable;
    }
}
```

I know such thing does not exist in C#, but it would be nice if there was something equivalent or as clean.

Comment: Your second code fragment is the correct way to do it. The third fragment will also work, I would initialize the local variable: `bool ok = false;`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on _why_ exactly the `catch` approach is the "correct" one, perhaps in an answer? Also, about the initialization, I think it is debatable, but I tend to follow Resharper's warnings and in this case it would be a redundant initialization since `bool`'s default value is `false`.

Comment: I simply prefer not to use additional variable when there is a construct that achieves the goal without it.

Comment: That's my own reasoning for preferring the `catch` approach also, but I'd like to see some sort of official or 'proven' best method. I have some doubts for instance, if both methods have the same performance. We all know exception handling is "slow" (when actually catching exceptions, not so much when throwing them), so I wonder if the `catch` version could be slower somehow, even though it does not catch the exception to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case (which is reasonably unusual I might add) you're passing responsibility of disposing of the object from this method to its caller when you return the disposable resource.

Obviously returning an already disposed object would be rather pointless for the caller, as they'd never be able to use it.  That rules out the last option here.

You want to dispose of the object in the event that you are not able to properly initialize it, which means disposing of it in the event that there is an exception, which is exactly what your first proposal does in the most straightforward manner.  Your second approach functions identically to your first, it's just not quite so straightforward in how it goes about doing it.

Using a `finally` block (generally hidden inside of `using` for simplicity) is appropriate when there is a method responsible for disposing of the resource and where *the lifetime of the disposable resource is the same as the scope of the variable you are storing it in*.  That tends to be the case for the vast majority of usages of disposable resources, just not this one in particular.

Comment: "Obviously returning an already disposed object would be rather pointless for the caller, as they'd never be able to use it. That rules out the last option here." I think you misread my code there. In the last example, I was comparing a supposedly new construct (new `release` keyword) with the C++ Scope Guard classes. I was aware that a normal `using` block would not work at all.

Comment: @julealgon In that case yes, it doesn't exist in C# and thus isn't possible.

Comment: Also, given our current code and how many of those warnings have appeared, I kindly disagree with your statement about transfering ownership of the disposable being "reasonably unusual". From my experience, this happens quite a lot.

Comment: @julealgon Then the code base that you're working on, or the idioms that your application is using, are likely inconsistent with the majority of C# applications.

Comment: Fair enough. We agree to disagree, then. Perhaps it's our own use of factory methods and handling of IoC containers that are causing more of those warnings than usual. There is also some ASPNET Identity classes that tend to handle a lot of nested `IDisposable` instaces that tend to raise these warnings if we do not handle exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Many languages require annoyingly-awkward constructs to discover when exceptions occurs without catching them.  This generally compels a trade-off between using awkward but semantically-precise code to work around that limitation while refraining from catching an exception one can't handle, or else tolerating the semantic imprecision of catching an exception which one can't possibly handle and then rethrowing it.  My personal preference is to use the semantically-correct-but-awkward code until such time as language implementers allow semantically-correct code to be written cleanly, but many others prefer to tolerate the semantic sloppiness of catching and unconditionally rethrowing exceptions.

Note that there is some benefit to *consistently* avoiding such catch-and-rethrow behavior, but not much will be gained by avoiding such behavior in a few places if the rest of one's code is rife with it.  Tolerating syntactic awkwardness to maintain semantic cleanliness is IMHO a good thing, but if things are already semantically dirty, writing code which is syntactically awkward but can't fix the underlying dirtiness may not be so worthwhile.

Of course, if the maintainers of .NET languages could let code do the right thing in syntactically-clean fashion, the whole issue would become moot.

Comment: Took me a while to fully understand your answer. I think your reasons are reasonable, though I have to question why you think the `catch` version is semantically imprecise. I think @Servy put it nicely in "You want to dispose of the object in the event that you are not able to properly initialize it, which means disposing of it in the event that there is an exception, which is exactly what your first proposal does in the most straightforward manner". I kind of agree with him on this, but I still have doubts concerning other fronts, like if it would be slower to rethrow instead of not catching.

Comment: @julealgon: The .NET Framework is designed to defer processing `finally` blocks until after all it executes all the first-pass exception filters between the source of an exception and the place it will be handled.  A catch and rethrow will circumvent this.  The popularity of catch-and-rethrow limits the usefulness of the two-pass model, but it can offer some advantages when debugging; it can also be used to detect some cases where an exception gets overwritten by a second exception which occurs during stack unwinding and code which wouldn't have handled the first exception handles the second.